# jQuery, Create multiple instances of div using custom attributes

Tags: jquery, html

I basically have multiple divs that contain information for different words (word, definition, ect.) all on one page. So each "word card" is written as the following (I took out some of the extra stuff):

```
<div id="card">
    <div class="card-info-box" id="definition" wordID="1">To lessen or get rid of any pain or suffering.</div>
    <a href="#" class="definition" wordID="1">Define</a> 
</div>
```

I added a custom attribute of "wordID" to each word. I am trying to use jQuery to create a "Define" link that toggles the appropriate #definition div. So far, I have the following jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#definition').hide();
    $(".definition").click(function(evt) {
        var d = $(this).attr("wordID");
        $("#definition[wordID=" + d + "], #definition[wordID=" + d + "]").toggle();
    }); 
});
```

Now with just one one card on a page, the jQuery works fine with toggling it's respective definition div. However, if I duplicate the card div and change the wordID to 2 on the second set, the second div's definition link does not do anything. The first one still works as it's supposed to.

Is there something I need to change so that the jQuery works correctly for each wordID attribute value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. You don't need use attribute selector, you could use `$(this).siblings('.card-info-box')` to select the div you want to toggle.

```
$(".definition").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.card-info-box').toggle();
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly!!! 

Here's a demo incase anyone else is wondering what it would look like. http://jsfiddle.net/HVVgH/

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Shiv Glad to help. And you should consider change id `card` to class `card`, should not exist duplicate ids.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID, even if they have different attributes. Try just using classes or data-item-name instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per previous answers, you can't have more than one element with the same id attribute on your page.

I've also tried working with custom attributes before, but they're problematic and not strict valid html. The approach I use now would be to use your wordID in the element's id attribute as follows:

```
<div id="card-1">
  <div class="card-info-box" id="definition-1">To lessen or get rid of any pain or suffering.</div>
  <a href="#" class="definition" id="define-word-1">Define</a>
</div> 
<div id="card-2">
  <div class="card-info-box" id="definition-2">A state of general wellbeing.</div>
  <a href="#" class="definition" id="define-word-2">Define</a>
</div>
```

and then construct the associated id value as required.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.card-info-box').hide();
  $(".definition").click(function(evt) {
        var d = $(this).attr("id").replace("define-word-", "");
        $("#definition-" + d).toggle();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

(edited to add a return value to prevent the clicked link being followed / browser jumping back to the top of the page)

Comment: This also works perfectly! I like how you also added the default state as hide(). Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You're welcome! I think xdazz's solution is superior for your particular question, but my solution will work (in general) if someone doesn't necessarily want the anchors wrapped in the same div as the elements to be displayed.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that I might need to use your solution since I don't have the anchors wrapped in the same div as the display element haha!

Comment: Hey Heather! So I'm using your method and it's working out perfectly! Now lets say I have a bunch of word cards on the page and half-and-half are toggled open or close. How could I provide a link at the top of the page that toggles all open (no matter their current state) and also vis versa? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to worry about calling .toggle() at all - just apply the .show() (or .hide()) method to the whole class.